# Data not being displayed in tabs

Tags: php, html, css

I am displaying data from database which is linked to CMS. The problem I get is data from only one of my tabs is being displayed. Suppose I have two tabs, Tab 1, Tab 2. Instead of Tab 1 being active, Tab 2 is active and data is displayed of Tab 2. But, when I click on Tab 1, no data with respect to Tab 1 is displayed. The same data is present i.e Tab 2 data. 
I am using mapping to get the ids of respective Tab.

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
<?php 
    if(isset($X['list_by_parent_id'][0]) && !empty($X['list_by_parent_id'][0]))
    {
        $top_category_index=1;
        foreach ($X['list_by_parent_id'][0] as $category_id)
        { 
        ?>
            <li class="tab-title <?php if($top_category_index==1){  echo "active"; }?>"><a href="#category-<?php echo $top_category_index++ ?>" class="category-name"><?php echo $SITE['tmp']['product_categories'][$category_id] ?></a></li>
        <?php
        }
    } 
?>
</ul>
```

**X** is a global variable which is an array and stores everything.

This is the code that does mapping and displays the content.

```
<div class="category-content">
                <div class="menu-cat-content tabs-content">
                <?php if(isset($SITE['category_list_by_parent_id'][0]) && !empty($SITE['category_list_by_parent_id'][0]))
                    {
                        $top_category_index_mapped=1;
                        foreach ($SITE['category_list_by_parent_id'][0] as $category_id)
                        { ?>
                        <div id="category-<?php echo $top_category_index_mapped; ?>" class="content <?php if($top_category_index_mapped++==1) { ?>active<?php } ?>">
//code for content
</div>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="category-content">
                <div class="menu-cat-content tabs-content">
                                        <div id="category-1" class="content active">

                        <!--sub category 1-->
                                                    </div><!--sub-category-clearfix2-->
                        <!--sub category 2 ends-->


                    </div> <!--category-div, index_mapped -->
                                            <div id="category-2" class="content active">

                        <!--sub category 1-->
                                                    </div><!--sub-category-clearfix2-->
                        <!--sub category 2 ends-->


                    </div> <!--category-div, index_mapped -->
                                            <div id="category-3" class="content active">
```

EDIT: I saw that top_category_index_mapped was set to 1 in category-*top_category_index_mapped. I replaced it and rendered html now looks like this.

Comment: Show js that switches tabs.

Comment: What is contained in the tabs, only hyperlinks?

Comment: I edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: Tabs contents are fetched my CMS, which is already coded and working well.

Comment: You need AJAX to do this properly. As you can see, all tabs are active all the time. You need client side script to set the tabs active according to what the user clicks on.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$top_category_index=1;
```

sets the `$top_category_index` to `1` for the first tab. This line:

```
<li class="tab-title <?php if($top_category_index==1){  echo "active"; }?>
```

is equal to this the firs two times:

```
<li class="tab-title active">
```

because of the properties of the `++` operator. [Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

For example:

```
$a = 5;
echo "Should be 5: " . $a++ . "<br />\n";
echo "Should be 6: " . $a . "<br />\n";
```

Since you've only tested with two tabs it seems, that's why you are getting those results. It might also be helpful to include the rendered html.

Comment: He is incrementing it `$top_category_index++`

Comment: I know, I updated my answer. I had misread it the first time.

Comment: So should I increment $top_category_index before the loop ends?

Comment: First of all try it with more than two tabs and see if you get the same results. Can you also include the rendered html so I can see what exactly happens?

Comment: Yes, I added three tabs. Still the same data is displayed. As previous. Just the order changed. The new Tab became Tab 2, and the previous Tab 2 became Tab 3 of which data is displayed.